# Looping through document backward in MongoDB Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have succesfully implemented a Next button in my application which loops through a collection and searches for the next document when the next button is pressed. I did this through,

```
DBCursor foo = coll.find().skip(count).limit(1); count++; //
```

after a user suggested me to do this. It worked. Now i want to implement the previous button. Any ideas?

Comment: by the way your title does not really describe what you're trying to do.

Comment: count--? Maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you just need to do something like this:

```
if (count > 0) count--;
DBCursor foo = coll.find().skip(count).limit(1);
```